# How to hide internal methods in the Stack Trace in "Debug" window of Android Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm a Visual Studio guy, and now I have to develop Android applications in Eclipse.

There is a "Debug" toolwindow showing the call stack depth tree, but not only my methods are shown, but also those of the Android system.

How to make the tree show just my methods, much like Visual Studio's "Just my code" function?

Comment: You need to filter the stack trace..can you attach snapshot to be more clear ???